# Generating average values on dictionary of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the followings pandas dataframes:

```
phreatic_level_l2n1_28w_df.head()
       Fecha    Hora    PORVL2N1  # PORVLxNx column change their name in each data frame
0   2012-01-12  01:37:47    0.65
1   2012-01-12  02:37:45    0.65
2   2012-01-12  03:37:50    0.64
3   2012-01-12  04:37:44    0.63
4   2012-01-12  05:37:45    0.61

phreatic_level_l2n2_28w_df.head()
       Fecha    Hora    PORVL2N2 # PORVLxNx column change their name in each data frame
0   2018-01-12  01:58:22    0.71
1   2018-01-12  02:58:22    0.71
2   2018-01-12  03:58:23    0.71
3   2018-01-12  04:58:23    0.71
4   2018-01-12  05:58:24    0.71

phreatic_level_l4n1_28w_df.head()
       Fecha    Hora    PORVL4N1 # PORVLxNx column change their name in each data frame
0   2018-01-12  01:28:49    0.96
1   2018-01-12  02:28:49    0.96
2   2018-01-12  03:28:50    0.96
3   2018-01-12  04:28:52    0.95
4   2018-01-12  05:28:48    0.94
```

And so, successively until have 25 data frames of type `phreatic_level_l24n2_28w_df`

```
.
.
.
phreatic_level_l24n2_28w_df.head()
       Fecha    Hora    PORVL24N2 # PORVLxNx column change their name in each data frame
0   2018-01-12  01:07:28    1.31
1   2018-01-12  02:07:28    1.31
2   2018-01-12  03:07:29    1.31
3   2018-01-12  04:07:27    1.31
4   2018-01-12  05:07:27    1.31
```

Each row contains data frames on the **`PORVLxNx`** column has values per day on the date range ( `Fecha` column) from `2018-01-12` until `2018-08-03` , having per each day many values of **`PORVLxNx`** column

```
phreatic_level_l24n2_28w_df.tail()
           Fecha    Hora    PORVL24N2
4875    2018-08-03  20:31:01    1.15
4876    2018-08-03  21:31:00    1.15
4877    2018-08-03  22:31:01    1.16
4878    2018-08-03  23:31:02    1.17
4879    NaN NaN NaN
```

My objective is to take each dataframe and generate the average **`PORVLxNx`** per day, as follow:
    Fecha          PORVL2N1
    0 2018-01-12  0.519130
    1 2018-01-13  0.138750
    2 2018-01-14  0.175417
    3 2018-01-15  0.111667
    4 2018-01-16  0.291250

I have the following approach:

I placed my `DataFrame`s in a dict and I referenced it suing a string:

```
dfs = {
    'phreatic_level_l2n1_28w_df': phreatic_level_l2n1_28w_df,
    # FOR THE MOMENT I ONLY TEST with the first dataframe 

    # 'phreatic_level_l2n2_28w_df': phreatic_level_l2n2_28w_df,
    # 'phreatic_level_l4n1_28w_df': phreatic_level_l4n1_28w_df,
    # 'phreatic_level_l5n1_28w_df': phreatic_level_l5n1_28w_df,
    # 'phreatic_level_l6n1_28w_df': phreatic_level_l6n1_28w_df,
    # 'phreatic_level_l7n1_28w_df': phreatic_level_l7n1_28w_df,
    # 'phreatic_level_l8n1_28w_df': phreatic_level_l8n1_28w_df,
    # 'phreatic_level_l9n1_28w_df': phreatic_level_l9n1_28w_df,
    # 'phreatic_level_l10n1_28w_df': phreatic_level_l10n1_28w_df,
    # 'phreatic_level_l13n1_28w_df': phreatic_level_l13n1_28w_df,
    # 'phreatic_level_l14n1_28w_df': phreatic_level_l14n1_28w_df,
    # 'phreatic_level_l15n1_28w_df': phreatic_level_l15n1_28w_df,
    # 'phreatic_level_l16n1_28w_df': phreatic_level_l16n1_28w_df,
    # 'phreatic_level_l16n2_28w_df': phreatic_level_l16n2_28w_df,
    # 'phreatic_level_l18n1_28w_df': phreatic_level_l18n1_28w_df,
    # 'phreatic_level_l18n2_28w_df': phreatic_level_l18n2_28w_df,
    # 'phreatic_level_l18n3_28w_df': phreatic_level_l18n3_28w_df,
    # 'phreatic_level_l18n4_28w_df': phreatic_level_l18n4_28w_df,
    # 'phreatic_level_l21n1_28w_df': phreatic_level_l21n1_28w_df,
    # 'phreatic_level_l21n2_28w_df': phreatic_level_l21n2_28w_df,
    # 'phreatic_level_l21n3_28w_df': phreatic_level_l21n3_28w_df,
    # 'phreatic_level_l21n4_28w_df': phreatic_level_l21n4_28w_df,
    # 'phreatic_level_l21n5_28w_df': phreatic_level_l21n5_28w_df,
    # 'phreatic_level_l24n1_28w_df': phreatic_level_l24n1_28w_df,
    # 'phreatic_level_l24n2_28w_df': phreatic_level_l24n2_28w_df  

}
```

I am iterating over the data frames (in this moment just over `phreatic_level_l2n1_28w_df` )

```
for name, df in dfs.items():
    # We turn to datetime the Fecha column values 
    df['Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Fecha'])

    # I am iterating over each *`PORVLxNx`* column
    for i in range(1,24):
        if(i==2):
            # To N1
            l2_n1_average_per_day = (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Fecha', freq='D'))['PORVL{}N{}'.format(i,i-1)].mean().reset_index())
            l2_n1_average_per_day.to_csv('L{}N{}_average_per-day.csv'.format(i,i-1), sep=',', header=True, index=False)
            print(l2_n1_average_per_day.head())
```

And my output of `l2_n1_average_per_day.head()` is:

```
    Fecha  PORVL2N1
0 2018-01-12  0.519130
1 2018-01-13  0.138750
2 2018-01-14  0.175417
3 2018-01-15  0.111667
4 2018-01-16  0.291250

l2_n1_average_per_day.tail()

        Fecha  PORVL2N1
199 2018-07-30  0.630417
200 2018-07-31  0.609583
201 2018-08-01  0.533333
202 2018-08-02  0.470833
203 2018-08-03  0.713333
```

Until here, my idea it's works.

When I want to apply this solution (is very possible that there is not the more optimal) to other data frames contained in my `dfs` dictionary

```
dfs = {
        'phreatic_level_l2n1_28w_df': phreatic_level_l2n1_28w_df,
        'phreatic_level_l2n2_28w_df': phreatic_level_l2n2_28w_df,
        # I've added the L2N2  phreatic_level_l2n2_28w_df dataframe item       
    }
```

**I've iterate again** ...

```
for name, df in dfs.items():
    df['Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Fecha'])
    for i in range(1,24):
        if(i==2):
            # To N1
            l2_n1_average_per_day = (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Fecha', freq='D'))['PORVL{}N{}'.format(i,i-1)].mean().reset_index())
            l2_n1_average_per_day.to_csv('L{}N{}_average_per-day.csv'.format(i,i-1), sep=',', header=True, index=False)

            # To N2. I've generate the average per day to L2N2

            l2_n2_average_per_day = (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Fecha', freq='D'))['PORVL{}N{}'.format(i,i)].mean().reset_index())
            l2_n2_average_per_day.to_csv('L{}N{}_average_per-day.csv'.format(i,i), sep=',', header=True, index=False)
```

In my output, the `PORVL2N2` is not found.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-161-fbe6eaf8a824> in <module>()
     11             print(phreatic_level_l2_n1_average_per_day.tail())
     12             # To N2
---> 13             phreatic_level_l2_n2_average_per_day = (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Fecha', freq='D'))['PORVL{}N{}'.format(i,i)].mean().reset_index())
     14             phreatic_level_l2_n2_average_per_day.to_csv('L{}N{}_average_per-day.csv'.format(i,i), sep=',', header=True, index=False)
     15 

~/anaconda3/envs/sioma/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    265         else:
    266             if key not in self.obj:
--> 267                 raise KeyError("Column not found: {key}".format(key=key))
    268             return self._gotitem(key, ndim=1)
    269 

KeyError: 'Column not found: PORVL2N2'
```

This is strange, because in my dataframe inside the dictionary, which is iterated, I have the `PORVL2N2` column

```
phreatic_level_l2n2_28w_df.head()
       Fecha    Hora    PORVL2N2
0   2018-01-12  01:58:22    0.71
1   2018-01-12  02:58:22    0.71
2   2018-01-12  03:58:23    0.71
3   2018-01-12  04:58:23    0.71
4   2018-01-12  05:58:24    0.71
```

Is possible, that in my iteration, I am overriding the data frames or something else is happening?

Comment: The problem is at your first iteration, in your loop `for name, df in ...` when `df` is `phreatic_level_l2n1_28w_df` then you look for the column `PORVL2N1` and it works, but after you also look for `PORVL2N2` in this `df` too, as nothing prevent to run the line `l2_n2_average_per_day = ...` when `df = phreatic_level_l2n1_28w_df`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dataframes seem to have a good and consistent structure, so what you can do is to get the name of the column you want `PORVLxNy` to get the `mean` from with `df.columns` and the last element `[-1]`. Then to save the result to a csv file with the right name, you can just keep the last 4 characters of the name of the column:

```
for name, df in dfs.items():
    df['Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Fecha'])
    col = df.columns[-1] #here col = PORVLxNx with the right x depending on df
    # no need of loop for anymore
    lx_ny_average_per_day = (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Fecha', freq='D'))[col]
                               .mean().reset_index())
    lx_ny_average_per_day.to_csv( '{}_average_per-day.csv'.format(col[-4:]), 
                                  sep=',', header=True, index=False)
```

Comment: With `col = df.columns[-1]` I am navigating in the right sense through of all columns on `df`  ... It's similar to slices concept?

Comment: @bgarcial Yes it is the same idea, knowing that the `-` sign means you go from the end :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd agree with @Ben.T about just using the last entry of the dataframe's columns `df.columns[-1]` for indexing, assumed the structure of your dataframes fits to this.
If not, another approach would be to just use the according substring of your dict-keys for indexing:

```
'PORV{}'.format(name.split('_')[2].upper())
```

or simply

```
'PORV' + name.split('_')[2].upper()
```

However, IMO you could also simplify the `groupby`-part, if you extract the right column as a `Series` with `Fecha`, i.e. date, as index, which enables you to use resampling functions, which exactly do grouping of timebased data like you want it to achieve:

```
sr = df.set_index('Fecha')['PORVL2N1']   # for indexing, the same like above applies again here
sr.index = pd.to_datetime(sr.index)
avg_per_day = sr.resample('D').mean()
```